# How the Alter Table command is handled by SQLServer?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, alter-table

We are using SQL Server 2008. We have an Existing database and it was required to `ADD` a new `COLUMN` to one of the `Table` which has **2700 rows** only but one of its column is of type `VARCHAR(8000)`. When i try to add new column (`CHAR(1) NULL`) by using `ALTER` table command, it takes too much time!! it took **5 minutes** and the command was still running to i stopped the command.
Below is the command, i was trying to add new column:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable Add ColumnName CHAR(1) NULL
```

1. Can someone help me to understand that How the SQL Server handles
   the ALTER Table command? what happens exactly?
2. Why it takes so much time to Add new column

**EDIT**:

1. What is the effect of **Table size** on **ALTER Command**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Altering a table requires a schema lock.  Many other operations require the same lock too.  After all, it wouldn't make sense to add a column halfway a `select` statement.

So a likely explanation is that a process had the table locked for 5 minutes.  The `ALTER` then has to wait until it gets the lock itself.

You can see blocked processes, and the blocking process, from the Activity Monitor in SQL Server Management Studio.

Comment: +1 for ALTER table require LOCK. Ok, so the size of the Table is nothing to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Well, one thing to bear in mind is that you were adding a new fixed length column to the table. The way that rows are structured in storage, all fixed length columns are placed before all of the variable length columns, for each row. So every row would have had to be updated in storage to make this change.

If, in turn, this caused the number of rows which could be stored on each page to change, a great many new allocations may have been required.

That being said, for the number of rows indicated, I wouldn't have though it should take 5 minutes - unless, as Andomar indicated, there was some lock contention also involved.